# What is the policy on very late exact duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, late-answers

It isn't uncommon that I will see an answer posted by a new user (often 1-rep) on a question which hasn't been active for over a year. What's more, this question already *has* an accepted answer. The new answer given is an *exact* duplicate of an existing one, to the point of being a possible copypasta.

When confronted with this, do we...

- ...downvote it?
- ...flag it for deletion?
- ...comment on it somehow?
- ...leave it alone?

I really don't feel like there's any obvious way to deal with this scenario, though it is not at all uncommon.

Comment: the answers from [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124944/what-is-the-correct-course-of-action-when-dealing-with-near-duplicate-answers) seem to answer your question (specially the accepted, which talks about _late_ dup answers)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an exact duplicate then you should leave a comment indicating that the licensing terms for Stack Exchange content require attribution to the original author.  If they don't respond, you should edit the answer to add the appropriate attribution so that they're not in violation of the license.

Comment: I like the edit approach over the rain-fire-and-brimstone approach. It's a way to teach someone something without exercising power over them and forcing them to do something. Hopefully, they'll do the right thing the next time to avoid confrontation and be a productive SE member.